# Replacing commas with periods in text for decimal numbers (python)?

Tags: python, python-re

1. I have a dataset, its field contains text information (there are both words and numeric data). As you can see in the screenshot, there are decimal numbers. They are separated by commas, and I need to make sure that there are periods between them.

[image]

I have previously tried writing a regex, but it replaces all commas in the text with periods.

```
Data_preprocessing['tweet_without_stopwords'] = Data_preprocessing['tweet_without_stopwords'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(",",'.', str(x)))
```

How do I write a regex so that it only works for decimal notations of a number? That is, I want an expression in the text of the form: `number,number` it was like this `number.number` in text.

2. Example broke the data

```
Data_preprocessing['tweet_without_stopwords'] = Data_preprocessing['tweet_without_stopwords'].apply(lambda x: re.sub("(\d*)\.(\d*)","\1,\2", str(x)))
```

[image]

Squares appeared :D

3.

```
Data_preprocessing['tweet_without_stopwords'] = Data_preprocessing['tweet_without_stopwords'].apply(lambda x: re.sub("(\d+)\,(\d+)","\1.\2", str(x)))
```

Result agan
[image]

Comment: so something like `(\d*)\.(\d*)` to `\1,\2`?

Comment: Yes, but I think it was the opposite -- change from "," to "."

Comment: @kostya ivanov do you want to go from e.g. `128,01` to `128.01` or the other way around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex you need is `"(\d+),(\d+)"` to `"\1.\2"`. Decomposition:

```regex
(\d+)       at least one digit (group 1)
,           a literal ,
(\d+)       at least one digit (group 2)
```

replace

```regex
\1         group 1
.          a period
\2         group 2
```

Applied to your code, the relevant section would be

```py
lambda x: re.sub(r"(\d+),(\d+)",r"\1.\2", str(x))
```

[Here's a testbed that verifies this regex is correct](https://regex101.com/r/Q2vGPV/2)

Comment: I am frozen, you can write this in code, please

Comment: Done. Not gonna write out your long array names (too lazy) but that should be enough to get you going.

Comment: This broke the data) Added a picture to the question

Comment: This looks to me that it will capture bare periods, as well. Somewhere at least one of the '*' needs to be a '+'.

Comment: yeah that one was an oversight. Repaired

Comment: @Jakob Lovern, I seem to be special, it doesn't work either. I'll add in the post what happens. Point 3

Comment: I think the strings need to be prefixed by "r": `re.sub(r"(\d+),(\d+)", r"\1.\2", str(x))`

Comment: @tromgy yes, it work, thanks

Comment: tromgy is right. I keep forgetting that regexes are like that in python